# How to get values on JSON result

Tags: jquery, json

I have one url that give the output below in JSON:

```
{
    "categorias": [
        {
            "id_categoria": 1,
            "nom_categoria": "Graduação"
        },
        {
            "id_categoria": 2,
            "nom_categoria": "Pós-Graduação"
        },
        {
            "id_categoria": 3,
            "nom_categoria": "Disciplinas"
        }
    ]
}
```

How I can extract only the values "Graduação","Pós-Graduação","Disciplinas" using Jquery?

Comment: Treat is as a big dictionary and use keys until you get to requred level dict_[key1][key2].. ect.

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

Comment: Post the code which you've tried :). Parse it then loop it.

Comment: I found a solution.   jsonObject.categorias[0].nom_categoria+jsonObject.categorias[1].nom_categoria+jsonObject.categorias[2].nom_categoria. Thank you everyone for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array#map` and fat arrow functions.

```js
let categorias = [
        {
            "id_categoria": 1,
            "nom_categoria": "Graduação"
        },
        {
            "id_categoria": 2,
            "nom_categoria": "Pós-Graduação"
        },
        {
            "id_categoria": 3,
            "nom_categoria": "Disciplinas"
        }
    ];
    
    let res = categorias.map(x=>x["nom_categoria"]);
    console.log(res);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me, because I can't change the page that give me result. In this case you modify some things in the data, like insert the 'let' text and remove '{}'

Comment: @fabiobh No, it doesn't modify anything. This is just to give you an idea as to how you can do it! For example the solution is same as `var categoriesName = yourJsonResponse.categorias.map(x=>x["nom_categoria"]);`. It's just shorter. It is called terse code. With ES6 people are now preferring this syntax over `function` syntax.

Comment: it works. I understand now, I think it's a better solution because I need to write less code and I consider that is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

use [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function

```
var categoriesName = yourJsonResponse.categorias.map(function(category) { 
    return category.nom_categoria;
});
```

if it is a string (not an object), you will need to parse it first. You can do it by using `JSON.parse()` function

Comment: Your solution works, thank you so much.